# Excel VBA to automatically click on webpage prompt

Tags: javascript, html, vba, excel

I was working with vba code to extract data from a specific webpage. I need to paste unique numbers in webpage and extract the details about those numbers and paste them in excel next to that number.

The problem is when that number is invalid I get a message from webpage to click ok so that I can paste the next unique number in webpage.
Codes works find until some invalid number is pasted and webpage message comes.

below is my VBA code:

```
Set iedoc = ie.document


   For i = 2 To k


With iedoc.forms(0)

Worksheets("ID").Select
'----------------
iedoc.all.txtNum.Value = Cells(i, "b").Value

  ie.document.getElementById("cmdSearch").Click


  Do While ie.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop
Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)

Cells(i, "c").Value = iedoc.all.LastName.Value
Cells(i, "d").Value = iedoc.all.txtAddress1.Value
Cells(i, "e").Value = iedoc.all.hdnName.Value



 ie.document.getElementById("cmdCancel").Click
    Do While ie.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop
'Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)

End With

 Next i
MsgBox "Downloading information is completed", vbOKOnly"
```

**And below is the HTML code I found useful for that message from Webpage**

```
Function OnLoadRoutine()
{
widthScreen = document.body.clientWidth ;
heightScreen = document.body.clientHeight ;

oFrm=document.frm;

preLoad();


        alert("Record not found for number: 275016159F7");


With (oFrm)

 {
if (optAll.checked == false && optSrchType[1].checked == false &&
    optSrchType[2].checked == false && optSrchType[3].checked == false &&
    optSrchType[4].checked == false)
    {
        optSrchType[0].status = true;
        optSrchType[0].checked = true;
        txtDCNNum.focus();
    }
```

}
}

Comment: send Enter or Escape key

Comment: I tried using that but still sometimes it get stuck. Is there anyway apart from sendkeys. Also I have to give timer before executing sendkey and it makes the code slower.

Comment: What makes that number invalid? Can you run the same logic from your code to determine if a number will be invalid before sending it to the web server? Or, another method could be to make the assumption that when your code quits interacting with the browser that the alert window is present and reload the page?

Comment: No those number by default comes invalid and there is no way to check them apart from checking them in the website. It's just I need to only extract info from valid ones by skipping the invalid as I said above.

Comment: have you tried send keys after using either [sleep or application.wait](http://www.exceltrick.com/formulas_macros/vba-wait-and-sleep-functions/)?

Comment: Yes I did with send keys with wait but it get stucked anywhere in between and the loop couldn't continue after that. I have to then manually click on ok so that loop can carry on.